# PC gets disconnected from wireless router after connecting laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a Dell Inspiron Laptop with Windows 7 and a PC with XP. 
The Laptop has Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN mini-card, i think it supports 802.11g. 
My PC has DLINK DWA 525 PCI WIRELESS card, this supports 802.11g and n. 
The wireless router is Belkin Surf Wireless Router (F7D2301zb).

Now, the problem i'm facing is when PC is connected first and later when laptop is connected, the computer gets disconnected. Laptop works fine. I have to restart the router to connect both.

I don't understand the problem. Is it due to the difference in 802.11 G and N of Laptop and PC ? How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

check to see if your laptop has a static IP address which happens to be the first address in your router's DHCP range. From what you are telling, this is a most probable cause. Also, on the router, make sure this laptop's assigned DHCP address is NOT a fixed address.

Comment: nope, both laptop and pc are using DHCP. There is no fixed addresses in router either.